# How do I get one element of Stack to appear outside another element?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart

[Here's the issue visually explained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1BiU.png) I am trying to use Stack widget to stack a text widget over a circle avatar placed on the center.
The text widget seems to get clipped when I try to use Positioned widget to place it to the bottom&right outside of the circle Avatar.

```dart
Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
                // circle avatar has to be on the center
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 40, //making the border of circleAvatar appear amber colored
                  backgroundColor: Colors.amber[900],
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    // backgroundImage:
                    //     AssetImage('assets/images/img1.png'),
                    radius: 38,
                  ),
                ),

                // this has to be on the right near the  circle avatar on the same row
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 0,
                  right: 0,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      Text('Dummytext1'),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 5,
                        width: 5,
                      ),
                      Text('dummytext2')
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add [clipBehaviour](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack/clipBehavior.html) to the Stack

```
Stack(
  clipBehaviour: Clip.none,
  children: <Widget>[
]
),
```

This will force it to not clip any overflowing content